# What are all the Factions i can join and their restrictions

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

I have started a new game, in previous playthroughs i normally just join the Fighters Guild but this time i'm going to try and complete as many quests as i can, that includes all factional quests.

in a previous playthrough after after i got so far though the Fighters Guild i went to join the Thieves Guild but was rejected, in another playthrough where i was in the Thieves Guild i was rejected from joining the Mages Guild. in each playthough i had at least 2 skills which would work with each guild which i was building (a basic set of skills i always select)

- Thieves Guild - Acrobatics, Athletics, Security
- Mages Guild - Alchemy, Restoration

since i want to try and complete every quest for every factions and given how i was rejected from Guilds in previous playthroughs i am wondering what all the Factions are which i can join and any restrictions which may stop me getting in later in the game or any quests that i end up doing which could see me kicked out.

This is a list of Factions i am aware of

- Blades
- Fighter Guild
- Mages Guild
- Thieves Guild
- Morag Tong
- Imperial Legion
- Imperial Cult

Comment: Do you count the houses as factions?  And fyi you can't join the morag tong

Comment: @z' i didn't know i can join the houses, when i say factions i mean any group that's listed in the Factions section which is why i included the Blades despite having never found a side quest for them

Comment: @z' also you can [join the morag tong](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Morag_Tong), that Wiki says you can and i remember finding their base in Balmora and being told i had to go to Vivec in order to join which was the first time i had to leave Balmora to join a Guild (having previously join the Fighters/Mages/Thieves Guilds in Balmora) i remember hording all my Writs which i remember that if i killed a person and the guards came for me i could show them that and get off free, that Wiki also lists the Writs you can get

Comment: yer right i was thinking of the cammoran tong, not morag tong, its been a while since I played morrorwind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a complete list of the joinable factions in Morrowind. A quick Google search of any one of them should be able to help you find any notes regarding how you join them. Don't forget: Joining certain factions closes you off to other ones, and you cannot advance in certain factions beyond a certain point if you've already done a certain amount in another faction. For example, if you've killed the heads of the Thieves Guild for the Fighter's Guild questline, you obviously cannot advance in the Thieves Guild without console commands. There are other NPC factions, and not all these factions will appear in your faction list, but they are all player factions nonetheless.

**House Hlaalu**

**House Redoran**

**House Telvanni**

**Blades** (Necessary, joined during the main quest)

**East Empire Trading Company** (Comes with Bloodmoon Expansion)

**Fighters Guild**

**Imperial Cult**

**Imperial Legion**

**Mages Guild**

**Thieves Guild**

**Ashlander Tribes** (Only technically one faction, but becoming friendly with the Ahemmusa, Erabenimsun, Zainabs, and Urshilaku puts you on friendly terms with all the others. You automatically do this during the Trials in the main quest)

**Morag Tong** (don't listen to the comments that say you cannot join. This is FALSE. You can join by going to their Vivec headquarters in the Arena Canton. In the storage area underneath the arena, talk to Eno Hlaalu. He can initiate you with a quest. This is the only way to join, you cannot join in their guild halls)

**Tribunal Temple**

**Aundae Clan**

**Berne Clan**

**Quarra Clan** (These are vampire clans. You can only join ONE of them. It will not appear in your faction list, but it will affect the bonuses you receive as a vampire, and what vampire quests are available to you.)

Hope this helped! :D

**UPDATE**

As for the latter part of your question, if you go to this page on the wiki:

http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Factions

There is a chart down at the bottom that shows the prospective relationships between the guilds, including NPC factions. What that means is that it shows the likelihood to like and/or attack you on sight based on your belonging factions.

Comment: Update: I just recently saw that you guys corrected yourselves about the Morag Tong. My bad!